# Are migrations done automatically?

Tags: support, migration

I posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456892/is-it-ok-to-set-a-background-image-in-the-html-element that was migrated to SO within 5 seconds of being posted.

Is there are bot that does this or was a moderator really on the ball?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was me. You posted it just before I came to the site so I saw it immediately. I am not a bot, I swear. :)

Comment: :o)  It happened so quickly I wasn't sure.  But they refused the migration...what I thought was a legitimate question doesn't seem to have a home

Comment: There are few bots that could compare to John, he's always really on the ball :-)

Comment: "I am not a bot, I swear. :)" You have to prove it :-p

Comment: I am not sure, perhaps someone can confirm this, but I seem to remember John Conde being the newest Marvel super hero SE Modman! What would be his powers? Reading posts before they appear seems like one for sure.